# Issue with popBackStack and orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments, orientation, fragmentmanager

I have a problem with fragments and the back stack after orientation change. In my app I add a new fragment to the back stack after button click like this:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fl_root_calendar_container,
                                DayFragment.newInstance(monthDayView.getDateTime(), mCalendarListener), DayFragment.TAG).
                                addToBackStack(null).setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN).commit();
```

If I click on the back button to revert the transaction after orientation change with the following code:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
   if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
       fm.popBackStack();
   }
```

I see the previous fragment again. Everything's fine. But the views are stretched or compressed after changing to landscape/portrait view. I'm not using

```
setRetainInstance(...)
```

The lifecycle callback

```
onCreateView(...)
```

is called in the previous fragment after orientation change, but the views inside the restored fragment haven't changed their sizes due to current orientation. Is there a way to fix this somehow?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you asking. Can you be clear - what you have and what you expect? Maybe screenshots will help.

Comment: I want the views inside fragment to be layout correctly. I show one fragment with some views inside it and on button click I add a new fragment to back stack. After orientation change and after popping the top fragment from back stack, the first fragment's views are not layout correctly, they have the sizes from the previous orientation. How can I achieve it, to requesting new layout sizes? It looks like a bug. I hope one can understand my problem...